# "bash: No such file or directory" but the file exists

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm trying to run a specific file using the code below on desktop ubuntu

```
source /mnt/d/Xilinx/Vivado/2021.1/settings64.sh
```

However, I keep getting hit with

```
-bash: D:\Xilinx\DocNav\.settings64-DocNav.sh: No such file or directory
-bash: D:\Xilinx\Vivado\2021.1\.settings64-Vivado.sh: No such file or directory
-bash: D:\Xilinx\Vitis\2021.1\.settings64-Vitis.sh: No such file or directory
-bash: D:\Xilinx\Model_Composer\2021.1\.settings64-Model_Composer.sh: No such file or directory
-bash: D:\Xilinx\Vitis_HLS\2021.1\.settings64-Vitis_HLS.sh: No such file or directory
```

I'm confused as to why can the file not be found when I can see it existing in the folder and when I run an ls command

Here is an image of the command prompt
[image]

I have seen a few posts with similar problems but I don't quite understand their solutions. Any clarification would be appreciated.

settings64.sh file contents

```
source 'D:\Xilinx\DocNav\.settings64-DocNav.sh'
source 'D:\Xilinx\Vivado\2021.1\.settings64-Vivado.sh'
source 'D:\Xilinx\Vitis\2021.1\.settings64-Vitis.sh'
source 'D:\Xilinx\Model_Composer\2021.1\.settings64-Model_Composer.sh'
source 'D:\Xilinx\Vitis_HLS\2021.1\.settings64-Vitis_HLS.sh'
```

Comment: Those are DOS/Windows paths, not unix (/Linux) paths.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I'm running the ubuntu desktop app on a Windows OS. Is there some other way I'm supposed to define my paths?

Comment: As long as you work within Linux (or WSL) you'll have to use the Linux-style paths (i.e. the ones starting with `/mnt/c/users` for example) and not the Windows-paths (`C:\Users`). [`wslpath` could help with converting one to the other, if necessary](https://superuser.com/questions/1113385/convert-windows-path-for-windows-ubuntu-bash).

Answer (score 0):

can you check the fill content of settings64.sh.
Because in Linux we don't mount volumes with letters like C:// or D://

According to me that script is not made for the supported OS you running on.

Let me know if I am wrong and I will edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: So will the sh script only run on a Linux system?. I'm running Windows 10 OS. if that's the case I do have an alternative settings64.bat file. Is this more appropriate to run on a Windows OS?

Comment: I have edited in the settings64.sh file contents above. Could you please take a look? thanks

Comment: The settings64.sh contains Files for Windows system.

Try to execute command "bash /mnt/d/Xilinx/Vivado/2021.1/settings64.sh"
But before that make sure that you have following files in D:// Directory....

because according to me Script is trying to add some enviromental paths using source. 
So just confirm that in D:// directory you have following files in the proper location.

Comment: @Sajidur: yes `.sh` are shell scripts and only really run on unix-like OS (Linux, BSD, Mac OS X, ...) and `.bat` are Windows batch files (technically MS-DOS used  them as well, IIRC). It's common for projects that work on both to include both a `.sh` and a `.bat`. Pick the appropriate one.